# Changing struts-rest idParameterName per action class

Tags: java, struts2

I want to have different idParameterNames for different action classes. Is that possible or do I have to write my own mapper?

Comment: @Darrel Miller: I'm just curious about why you removed the "rest"-tag?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. The `struts.mapper.idParameterName` is used by the `RestActionMapper` and the parameter is parsed prior to the `ActionMapping` being returned (i.e., before the action to use is known).